# JQUERY Select boxon change function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, html-select

Even though I select data in the select box, it does not change inside the select box form. It works after deleting the form, but I can't access it while the form exists.

html code:

```
<form id="selectFormLanguage" action="" class="language-picker__form">
  <label id="labelSelectData" for="language-picker-select">Select your language</label>
  <select onchange="getval(this);" name="language-picker-select" id="language-picker-select">
    <option lang="en-US" value="english">English</option>
    <option lang="fr-FR" value="francais">Français</option>
    <option lang="tr-TR" value="turkey">Türkçe</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

JS codes:

```
$('#language-picker-select').find('option').click(function() {
    var optionSelected = $(this);
    var valueSelected = optionSelected.val();
    var textSelected = optionSelected.text();
    console.log('dasdasdas')
});
```

Comment: You have missing code for `getval`,also you need bind event on `select` rather than `option`

Answer (score 0):

You must create the `getval` function, and then call it.

```js
const getval = ()=>{
  var selectedText = $('#language-picker-select').find(":selected").val();
  console.log(selectedText);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="selectFormLanguage" action="" class="language-picker__form">
      <label id="labelSelectData" for="language-picker-select">Select your language</label>
      <select onchange="getval();" name="language-picker-select" id="language-picker-select">
          <option lang="en-US" value="english">English</option>
          <option lang="fr-FR" value="francais">Français</option>
          <option lang="tr-TR" value="turkey">Türkçe</option>
      </select>
</form>
```